# Is there a way to implement IfNull/Coalesce in DynamoDB PartiQL?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, coalesce, ifnull, partiql

DynamoDB PartiQL does not support an equivalent `IFNULL/COALESCE` built-in function yet (even though `COALESCE` is a [reserved keyword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html) and DynamoDB's sibling QLDB seems to support it with its [PartiQL implementation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-functions.coalesce.html), so it appears to be theoretically possible). Using only PartiQL, is there any way to construct an equivalent of SQL's,

```
SELECT COALESCE(col1, col2) FROM sometable;
```

with the functions/syntax currently supported?